# Update relation datas via prisma

Tags: node.js, typescript, relationship, updates, prisma

I am currently on a project and to develop my API I am using the ORM Prisma I am just starting to use it. I manage to do a classic CRUD except that I am confronted with an error that I do not understand that I did not have with TypeORM during the update, I explain to you.

Basically I have a Application table that looks like this:

```
model candidature {
  id                                  Int                                   @id @default(autoincrement())
  last_name                           String?                               @db.VarChar(255)
  first_name                          String?                               @db.VarChar(255)
....
  candidature_files                   candidature_files[]
}
```

I also have a **Candidature_files** table:

```
model candidature_files {
  id                     Int                    @id @default(autoincrement())
  file_id                Int
  is_checked             Boolean                @default(false)
  candidature_id         Int
  candidature            candidature            @relation(fields: [candidature_id], references: [id])
  candidature_files_list candidature_files_list @relation(fields: [file_id], references: [id])
 
  @@index([file_id], name: "candidature_files_candidature_ibfk_1")
  @@index([candidature_id], name: "candidature_files_candidature_ibfk_2")
}
```

And my problem is that I would like to be able to update the data of the **Candidature_files** at the same time as that of the **Candidature** and therefore send this kind of data:

```
"last_name":"Jean-Meulaine",
...
"candidature_files": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "file_id": 1,
                "is_checked": false,
                "candidature_id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "file_id": 2,
                "is_checked": true,
                "candidature_id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "file_id": 3,
                "is_checked": false,
                "candidature_id": 1
            }
        ]
```

But when I send such a form, it returns an error:

```
Invalid `prisma.candidature.update()` invocation:
 
{
  where: {
    id: 1
  },
  data: {
    last_name: 'Jean-Meulaine',
...
    candidature_files: [
      {
        id: 1,
        file_id: 1,
        is_checked: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        file_id: 2,
        is_checked: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        file_id: 3,
        is_checked: false
      }
    ]
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  },
  include: {
    candidature_files: true
  }
}
 
Argument candidature_files: Got invalid value
[
  {
    id: 1,
    file_id: 1,
    is_checked: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    file_id: 2,
    is_checked: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    file_id: 3,
    is_checked: false
  }
]
```

Here is my function for **update**, very basic:

```
public async update(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const candidatureId: number = parseInt(req.params.id);
    const candidature = req.body
 
    try {
        const updatedCandidature = await prisma.candidature.update({
    where:{
        id:candidatureId
    },
    data:
        candidature,
    include:{
        candidature_files:true
    }
     
})
res.json(updatedCandidature)
console.log(updatedCandidature);
 
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).json(error);
    }
}
```

There you go, I hope you have enough information to help me to solve this one a bit, thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `create`. It should be like this:

```
candidature_files: {
create: [
      {
        id: 1,
        file_id: 1,
        is_checked: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        file_id: 2,
        is_checked: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        file_id: 3,
        is_checked: false
      }
    ]
}
```

You can learn more about adding relation data here: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#nested-writes

**Update:**

As you need an update, it would need some configuration as follows:

```
const candidatureId: number = parseInt(req.params.id);
const candidature = req.body
const { candidature_files, ...rest } = candidature

  const updatedCandidature = await prisma.candidature.update({
    where: {
      id: candidatureId,
    },
    data: {
      ...rest,
      candidature_files: {
        update: candidature_files.map(({ id, ...data }) => ({
          where: { id: id },
          data,
        })),
      },
    },
    include: {
      candidature_files: true,
    },
  })
```

Comment: Thank you @Ryan for your comment but my problem is during an UPDATE and not a CREATE. My goal is to submit a form with all the informations about a candidature like Name,Email,etc... AND if for example the file_id = 2 is modified, update it... And in the examples I don't find the situation which is pretty current...